# Drupal: Convert taxonomy term name to term id

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Using 'taxonomy: term ID' as an argument in one of my Drupal views and I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly.

On the views administration page it states, "if using term name, it is generally more efficient to convert it to a term ID and use Taxonomy: Term ID rather than Taxonomy: Term Name."

How does one go about converting the term name from a URL into a term ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't show how do link to this views with agruments, if like this: http://site.com/views_page/taxonomy_name, then:
arg(1) - it's you term_name, get id via: `$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name(arg(1));`

 result is `$term->tid`

But if http://site.com/views_page/taxonomy_name - is aliased path to taxonomy terms, views should see directly tids in argument handling via arg(2) in taxonomy/term/TID path.

Comment: but how would I pass this value to my view argument?

Comment: Add argument on Views, see "Validator options", choose PHP code: read carefully comment there:  You may change the argument by setting "$handler->argument". So you can change name to tid here.

Comment: Note that $term->tid is null when you execute. any idea how  to solve this?

Comment: 2claire: if (!$term->tid) return false;